# JQuery Cycle Plugin - Go to specific slide in other page

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

In this link:

http://www.contactarte.com.pe/test/page1.html

I wonder if it possible to click in this page for example SLIDE4 button and go to next page showing the slide 4 in the slider.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, change your `href` to include a query string parameter to indicate the slide:

```
<a href="page2.html?slide=0">SLIDE 1</a>
<a href="page2.html?slide=1">SLIDE 2</a>
```

Then change the starting slide on page2 based on the query parameter passed in:

```
$('#rotating-item-wrapper').cycle({
    startingSlide: (getParameterByName('slide') || 0);
});
```

Using the following function to extract your query string parameters ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: Hi ther, thanks a lot for the answer, but i cannott make it work, im not too much into JS, it would help me if you can point me to the ride direction. Where did i need to paste that code?

Comment: The first section of HTML you already have, you just need to replace the <a> tags with the ones I've provided. The second block of code you also already have, you just need to replace the `startingSlide` value with the one I've provided. The third block of code is a new function you should place anywhere on page2.html

Comment: Hi there ! It worksss!! Thanksss !! Theres is only a little problem, hope it can be fix, with your code, if i only open page2.html it doesnt show any slide, any way to show always first slide by default??

Comment: @user3436320 Good question! Just change the `startingSlide` value to include a default. I've updated the answer to do exactly that. Now the startingSlide will default to 0 unless another value is provided. Also, please remember to mark this as the answer. Good luck! =D

Comment: Yuhuuu !! Works like a clock dude! Thanks a lot !! I really appreciated. (how i mark the answer?, im new asking questions in this site) :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! There should be a big hollow checkmark next to the answer. If you click it, it should mark this as the answer. Hopefully then the solution will help anyone with a similar question in the future.